# How to add a row record in empty Dataframe in Spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create an empty dataFrame in Spark scala and wanted to create the schema of my own and load the record into it.

Below is the example

```
val emptyDf = spark.emptyDataFrame

val loadEmptyDf = emptyDf.withColumn("col1", lit("yes"), "col2", lit("no"))
```

but i am not able to get the default value which i am putting while creating schema

Current Output:

```
|col1|col2|
|    |    |
```

expected Output:

```
|col1|col2|
|yes | no |
```

Answer (score 0):

`withColumn` add a column , and `lit` add default value to all row, but your `DataFrame` is empty ..

```
val data = Seq(Row("yes", "no"))

val schema: StructType = new StructType()
  .add("col1", StringType)
  .add("col2", StringType)

val df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data), schema)

df.show()

+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
| yes|  no|
+----+----+
```